# Laravel validateForm: prevent update when inactive

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to prevent an update in a record when the function `isActive` returns `false`.

Foo.php

```
// My Class

public function isActive() {
    return false;
}
```

FooForm.php

```
// My Form

public function validateForm()
{
    $this->validate($this->request, [
        'field_1'      => 'required',
        'field_2'      => 'required',
        'field_3'      => 'required',
        'isActive' => 'boolean:true'
    ]);
}
```

Expected: Block the update because `isActive` returns `false`.

Nowadays: Updating without any problem.

**EDIT**

`isActive` can't be database property.

Comment: well, `'isActive'` is supposed to be from the `$this->request` not a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking to implement a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules).

There are couple ways of doing it as per the linked documentation. Here's an example using the closure method:

```
public function validateForm()
{
    $this->validate($this->request, [
        'field_1'      => 'required',
        'field_2'      => 'required',
        'field_3'      => 'required',
        'isActive' => function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (!$this->isActive()) {
                $fail('isActive is false');
            }
        }
    ]);
}
```

If you need to chain it with other validation rules you can also put the closure into an array like so:

```
'isActive' => [
    'required',
    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        if (!$this->isActive()) {
            $fail('isActive is false');
        }
    }]
```